# How to mock an async axios request that is made by a helper function imported by the mobx store

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, axios, mobx

I'm trying to write tests for a method in my mobX store that calls a helper method `getPages` that makes an asynchronous API call to fetch some data. I was successfully able to mock axios when writing tests for the `getPages` helper function but now that I'm testing the mobx store I can't seems to mock axios anymore.

Is this because the store file doesn't import axios directly?

Do I have to mock `getPages` helper function instead? If so how would I do that?

Currently the API call `await axios.get('${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/pages');` is returning `undefined` instead of the mocked value. Ultimately I just need this call to returned the mocked value.

Thank you

MobX Store

```
import { makeAutoObservable } from 'mobx';
import { getPages } from 'lib/api';

class DocumentStore {
  pages = [];
  currentPage = null;

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }

  setPages = (pages) => {
    this.pages = pages;
    return this.pages;
  };

  setCurrentPage = (page) => {
    this.currentPage = page;
    return this.currentPage;
  };

  getPages = async (documentName) => {
    const pageUrls = await getPages('a-test', documentName);
    this.setCurrentPage(pageUrls[0]);
    this.setPages(pageUrls);
  };
}

export default DocumentStore;
```

API call

```
export const getPages = async () => {
  let resp;
  try {
    resp = await axios.get(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/pages`,
    );
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }

  if (resp?.data?.urls) {
    return resp.data.urls;
  } else {
    throw new Error('Unable to fetch Urls');
  }
};
```

Test File

```
import DocumentStore from './index';
import axios from 'axios';

const TEST_PAGES = [
  {
    url: 'URL1',
  },
  {
    url: 'URL2',
  },
  {
    url: 'URL3',
  },
];

const FETCH_PAGES_MOCK = {
  data: {
    urls: TEST_PAGES,
  },
};

jest.mock('axios');

describe('DocumentStore', () => {
  describe('getPages', () => {
    axios.get.mockResolvedValue(FETCH_PAGES_MOCK);
    it('fetches pages', () => {
      const store = new DocumentStore();
      expect(store.pages.length).toEqual(0);
      store.getPages();
      expect(store.pages.length).toEqual(3);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Mock indirect dependencies(`axios.get()`) and mock direct dependencies(`getPages` from `lib/api` module), both of them are ok.  Depends on which modules you want as a unit. I prefer smaller units, only mock modules that the tested code directly depends on.

Too large a unit will make the test more complicated and difficult to locate the problem. The huge unit is close to higher level testing, such as integration testing, e2e testing.

For your case, you forgot to use `await` when calling the `store.getPages()` method.

E.g.

`index.test.js`:

```js
jest.mock('axios');

describe('DocumentStore', () => {
  describe('getPages', () => {
    axios.get.mockResolvedValue(FETCH_PAGES_MOCK);
    it('fetches pages', async () => {
      const store = new DocumentStore();
      expect(store.pages.length).toEqual(0);
      await store.getPages('test');
      expect(store.pages.length).toEqual(3);
      expect(axios.get).toBeCalled();
    });
  });
});
```